# Exclude all dependencies matching pattern

Tags: scala, sbt

I am upgrading one of the my Scala projects to Scala 2.11.7, but it has some dependent projects. They are using 2.10 so it is referring to a lot of dependent libraries with 2.10 Scala version (ex: com.novus:salat-core_2.10:1.9.9). I want to exclude which and all having "_2.10-" instead of writing one by one.

Is this possible?

Comment: are talking about exclude or upgrade all to `2.11`

Comment: I upgraded 2.11, but still referring few 2.10 jars might be some incompatibility  reasons.

Answer (score 0):

1: Using scala version and providing sbt to choose correct version with `%%`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

val scalaz = "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0"
```

2: To exclude explicitly dependencies which has 2.10 build version use custom methods

```
// exclude from all with rule which check whether artifact name contains 2.10 
def excludeFromAll(items: Seq[ModuleID], group: String, artifact: String) =
  items.map(x => if(x.name.contains("_2.10")) x.exclude(group, artifact))

//all your dependencies
val deps = Seq(dependencies) //library Dependencies.

//exlusion
val appDependencies = excludeFromAll(deps, _, _)
```